# Elasticsearch query showing weird behavior : bug?

Tags: elasticsearch

To sum up things quickly, we are using Elasticsearch 6.8.4 and have documents with fields such as "statutPublicOuInterne" (public or internal state) or "identifiant" (identifier).
I cannot share the whole JSON (_source) for security reasons (corporate restrictions), but it looks like the following:

```
                "_source": {
                    "dateCreation": "2020-11-05T16:31:28.404+01:00",
                    "dateDerModif": "2020-11-05T16:31:49.183+01:00",
                    "contenu": { ... }
                    "langue": "fr",
                    "observations": null,
                    "statutPublicOuInterne": "enAttenteTraitementCommissionTask",
                    "identifiant": "SFB-20201105-ELUH",
                    (...)
                }
```

Some of the "statutPublicOuInterne" can have values such as "enAttenteTraitementCommissionTask" or "enCoursTraitementCommissionTask".

**1st question:** for some reason, when I search for statutPublicOuInterne=enCoursTraitementCommissionTask, it doesn't work, but if I search for statutPublicOuInterne=enCoursTraitementCommission (without "Task"), it works! That seems so weird to me and I really can't explain it.

**2nd question:** if I assume I need to search without the "Task" at the end, then searching for statutPublicOuInterne=enCoursTraitementCommission works but statutPublicOuInterne=enAttenteTraitementCommission doesn't work! (nor does statutPublicOuInterne=enAttenteTraitementCommissionTask work)

The query is as follows:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : [
                {
                    "match" : {
                        "statutPublicOuInterne" : {
                            "query" : "enAttenteTraitementCommission"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I just can't understand why it doesn't find anything, because if I search for this document with its "identifiant" field, then it works:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : [
                {
                    "match" : {
                        "identifiant" : {
                            "query" : "SFB-20201105-ELUH"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The response is:

```
{
    "took": 2,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 1,
        "max_score": 2.0283146,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "some-index",
                "_type": "demandes",
                "_id": "SFB-20201105-ELUH",
                "_score": 2.0283146,
                "_source": {
                    "dateCreation": "2020-11-05T16:31:28.404+01:00",
                    "dateDerModif": "2020-11-05T16:31:49.183+01:00",
                    "contenu": { ... }
                    "langue": "fr",
                    "observations": null,
                    "statutPublicOuInterne": "enAttenteTraitementCommissionTask",
                    "identifiant": "SFB-20201105-ELUH",
                    (...)
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

We can clearly see "statutPublicOuInterne": "enAttenteTraitementCommissionTask" in the response.

Am I missing something?

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "statutPublicOuInterne": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "dateCreation": "2020-11-05T16:31:28.404+01:00",
  "dateDerModif": "2020-11-05T16:31:49.183+01:00",
  "langue": "fr",
  "observations": null,
  "statutPublicOuInterne": "enAttenteTraitementCommissionTask",
  "identifiant": "SFB-20201105-ELUH"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "statutPublicOuInterne": {
              "query": "enAttenteTraitementCommissionTask"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "64700803",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "dateCreation": "2020-11-05T16:31:28.404+01:00",
          "dateDerModif": "2020-11-05T16:31:49.183+01:00",
          "langue": "fr",
          "observations": null,
          "statutPublicOuInterne": "enAttenteTraitementCommissionTask",
          "identifiant": "SFB-20201105-ELUH"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @qdeme did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :)

Comment: Hi Bhavya,
I don't understand how your example can work, because your suggested index mapping is about the same as mine:
`                    "statutPublicOuInterne": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        },
                        "analyzer": "default",
                        "search_analyzer": "default_search"
                    },`

Comment: @qdeme can you please share the index definition of the analyzers you are using ?

Comment: @qdeme It's been a long time. Can you please reply to my above comment? Or if you don't have any follow up question, and my answer helped you resolve your issue then please don't forget to upvote and accept my answer :)